# Opening Link in New Tab Search Item Display Template Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, search-results, display-template

I followed [this](http://merill.net/2013/05/tweaking-the-default-search-display-template-in-sharepoint-2013/) article to create a display item template for search. I want to open the title field in a new tab, right now when you click on the link from the search results, it opens in the same page. I have used a function on the onclick event of the href tag. But the link open on the same page and the function 'openInNewTab' is not getting called. Any Suggestions?

```
<script>
    function openInNewTab(url) {
                alert("openInNewTab function called");
                var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
                win.focus();
            }

</script>



var titleHtml = String.format('<a clicktype="{0}" onclick="openInNewTab(url); return false;" id="{1}" href="{2}" class="ms-srch-item-link custom-item-link" title="{3}" onfocus="{4}" {5}>{6}</a>',$htmlEncode(clickType), $htmlEncode(id + Srch.U.Ids.titleLink), $urlHtmlEncodeString(url),$htmlEncode(ctx.CurrentItem.Title),
                                                          showHoverPanelCallback, appAttribs, Srch.U.trimTitle(title, maxTitleLengthInChars, termsToUse));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried changing the anchor tag and add `target="_blank"` rather than the onclick event handler?